# add students in loop

Tags: python, c

```
void addStudent(char* lastName, 
                char* firstName, 
                char* studentId, 
                smartresponse_classV1_t* signInClass)
{

    sr_student_t *student = sr_student_create(
        lastName, 
        sizeof lastName + 1, 
        firstName, 
        sizeof firstName + 1, 
        studentId, 
        sizeof studentId);

    sr_class_addstudent(signInClass, student);

    sr_student_release(student);
}

// add student
char *firstName = "first";
char *lastName = "last";
char *studentId = "1";
char *id ="";
int i;

for ( i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    id = _itoa(i, studentId, 10);

    addStudent(lastName, firstName, id, signInClass);
}
```

I am trying to convert int to string so that I can assign new id for new student.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong because I call the test dll function from python and somehow it give me an error windowserror exception access violation writing ..... in print dll.test()
Is there a problem in the for-loop when I call the function and assign id to it??

```
def test(x):
    ''' Just runs the main test.
    >>> test(1)
    1
    '''

   if x == 1:
       print dll.test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ''' Testing the library. '''
    import doctest
    if doctest.testmod()[0] > 0:
        raise Exception('Unit tests have errors')
    print 'Unit tests OK'
```

Answer (score 0):

You assigned less bytes to your id and studentId pointers

```
 char *id =""; //1 byte assigned 0x00 at string "" end
 char *studentId ="1"; // 2 bytes assigned but in code you will need 3 ("10"+null)
```

Your code should look like this:

```
void addStudent(char* lastName, char* firstName, char* studentId, smartresponse_classV1_t* signInClass){
            sr_student_t *student = sr_student_create(lastName, sizeof lastName + 1, firstName, sizeof firstName + 1, studentId, sizeof studentId);
            sr_class_addstudent(signInClass, student);
            sr_student_release(student);
    }
char *firstName = "first";
char *lastName = "last";
char *studentId = "00";
char *id ="00";
int i;

for ( i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    id = _itoa(i, studentId, 10);
    addStudent(lastName, firstName, id, signInClass);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply but the problem is still there I Think there is a problem in calling dll test function. But it runs if i remove  the itoa call and id from the loop and run it with only student id ="1".   Please help me

Comment: If you remove `id = _itoa(i, studentId, 10);` and it runs. You should search there for your problem. `access violation` means that you trying to write somewhere that you are not allowed to.